# problem is in ASyncTask class in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

basically i am reading image bytes from file i have a loop which has to read almost 20 images from file and in this loop i have making the object of my class which extends ASyncTask class and i am reading bytes and drawing on canvas in `doItBackground()` method and setting my image on `onPostExecute()` method. so basically Asynchronously 20 threads starts execution in background. now problem is it is not showing any image.

anybody have any idea how to handle multiple AsyncTask class? here is my code.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
//      Log.i("start background thread", "start background thread");
        Set<Integer> keys;
        keys = iTileListOffsets.keySet();
        boolean found = false;
        Object key[] = keys.toArray();
        int k = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < key.length && found==false ; i++)
        {               
            k = (Integer) key[i];
            MapTileHeader tileHeader = iTileListOffsets.get(k);
            if (tileHeader.equalsWith(mapTile.getiMapTileHeader()) )
            {                   
                found = true; 
            }
        }

        if(found)
        {           
            try 
            {   
                synchronized (MapMaker.getSingletonObject()) 
                {
                    fc.position(0);                     
                    input.skipBytes(k);                         
                    int tSizeOfTile = input.readInt();              
                    mapTile.loadTileWithFileHeader(input, tSizeOfTile, headerBytesArray);
                }

                mapMaker.getBufferedTilesDataList().add(mapTile);                       
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            byte imageTile[] = mapTile.getImageTilesBytes();             //bufferedTile.getImageTilesBytes();                   

            if(mapTile.getImageTilesBytes() != null)
            {                       
                try
                {
                    Bitmap tileBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageTile, 0, imageTile.length);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(tileBitmap, rect.left, rect.top, null);
                    tileBitmap = null;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                   
            }
        }
//      Log.i("ENDDDD background thread", "ENDDD background thread");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);        
        Log.i("start POSTECEXCUTE thread", "start POSTECEXCUTE thread");

        MyRect mapRect = aBufferArea.GetScreenRectangle(buffer, aScrnArea); 
        Bitmap smallBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, mapRect.left, mapRect.top, mapRect.width, mapRect.height);         
        image.setImageBitmap(smallBitmap);

        Log.i("ENDDDDD POSTECEXCUTE thread", "ENDDDD POSTECEXCUTE thread");
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can update the UI directly from `doInBackground`, as the code in this method is run in a backgound thread and does not have direct access to the IU thread.  You can update the UI either from `onPostExecute` or from `onProgressUpdate`.  You can call the latter of these from `doInBackground` by calling `publishProgress`.

There is a simple example in the documentation for AsyncTask, and [this one](http://jyro.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-asynctask-template.html) is a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest a slightly different way of thinking about the problem. Instead of having a thing in the background which both downloads and draws the bitmaps, you might try making the doInBackground method decode and return the Bitmap, then draw it onto the canvas in onPostExecute. This arrangement should prevent you from having contention on the canvas.

Looking at the code you've posted, the loaded bitmaps get drawn onto canvas. Then bitmap gets displayed in image. I can't see, in the code you posted, anywhere that the loaded bitmaps canvas gets sent to the screen.

It might be worth double-checking that the image you're drawing to has a large enough height and width.